# Rewrite a user profile URL

Tags: php, nginx

Sorry if my title isn't very clear, I don't know how to word it.
For example I want to rewrite this URL:
**https://website.com/profile.php?uid=2** to something like:
**https://website.com/user/username**

My NGINX config is as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name website.com hiddenservice.onion;
        root /var/www/website;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php;

        add_header Onion-Location http://hiddenservice.onion$request_uri;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass website.com;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

Comment: This is a tricky thing. Technically possible, but the usability depends on what types of usernames can occur. The much more robust approach would be to use a URL like that: `https://website.com/user/2/username`. This keeps the numeric user ID which is missing otherwise. A missing user ID would mean you have to retrieve it from the database first. And this might get nasty if the user names contain characters besides plain ASCII.

Comment: Would profile.php?uid=username rewriting to /user/username be easier to implement?

Comment: The rewriting is not the issue. You'd face the same issue with non ASCII characters. And you'd have additional queries to your database each time. And you'd have to index the username in your database.

Comment: Oh alright, special characters aren't allowed in usernames.

Comment: @arkascha what exactly is the problem with non-ASCII characters? Further, if, in response to the query, you are going to select the user's details from the database in any case, then you can use any unique column to accomplish that: ID, username, or their phone number, or e-mail, or whatever else. Just have an (unique) index on that column to ensure lookup performance.

Comment: removing the mariadb and linux tags, as they are unrelated to the question